# Include two functions in (click) angular 5

Tags: angular

I want to include to two function on click

```
<li class="active" (click) ="routeTransaction(), activateClass(classChange)" *ngIf="permissionKeys.indexOf('TRANSACTIONS')>-1" [ngClass]="{'liactive': classChange}" >
    <a >
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>
          <span>Transaction</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

This is giving an error; how could it be fixed?

Comment: `(click) ="routeTransaction(); activateClass(classChange)" `

Comment: Do these run asynchronously? Correct me if I am wrong but you could chain the second function at the end of the first function, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Seperate them by semicolon. Its the same like writing multiple statements inside a block scope.

```
<li class="active" (click) ="routeTransaction(); activateClass(classChange)" *ngIf="permissionKeys.indexOf('TRANSACTIONS')>-1" [ngClass]="{'liactive': classChange}" >
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to separate by **`;`** not by **`,`**

```
 (click) ="routeTransaction(); activateClass(classChange)
```